# Перегрузка оператора [] с двумя аргументами типа a[i, j] в Python

Tags: python, перегрузка-операторов

Приветстсвую! Подскажите пожалуйста, как перегрузить оператор [], для того, чтобы можно было вызвать квадратные скобки у класса передав два аргумента a[i, j].

```
class A:
    def __getitem(self, val1, val2):
    return val1 + val2
```

Код выше не работает... Не нашёл как это можно реализовать, требуется помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [186]: class A(object):
     ...:     def __getitem__(self, vals):
     ...:         val1, val2 = vals
     ...:         return val1 + val2
     ...:

In [187]: a = A()

In [188]: a[3, 5]
Out[188]: 8
```